# How to redirect to next page using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#btn").on("change", function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
      url: "1.php",
      data: { id: val },
      success: function( result ) {
        alert("Hi, testing");
        alert( result );
      }
    });
  });
});
```

I want to redirect to `2.php?name=iamchecking` it shows alert msg "hi testing" but I want to send it to `2.php` and get the value of name from get on PHP. How can I do so?

Comment: `document.location.href="2.php?name=iamchecking";`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page
;)

Comment: `"it shows alert"` - That's what the `alert()` function does, yes.  `"i want to send it to 2.php"` - And when you Googled "JavaScript redirect" what did you find?  How did that code not work as expected?

Comment: @putvande i don't want page to reload. Adding this code reloads the page but i want it not be reloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Just write:

```
document.location.href = `2.php?name=iamchecking`
```

That'll redirect user to PHP page with GET arguments.

**UPDATE**

It is likely impossible to redirect without reloading. You can download content from website and then show it to user, however I don't know is that something what you expect.

---

However, there is Chrome specific solution to do that:

```
window.history.pushState(“object or string”, “Title”, “/new-url”);
```

It could work on other browsers, but doesn't have to.

You can read more, here: http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page/